# Cumulative plot with "duration" variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm having a hard time accurately plotting some data I have.

I have data of counts that was measured at some time points that I want to plot with a cumulative graph. The data have some rare high values that causes the plot to have large jumps.
Here is the current plot with  my try to smooth the line with `rolling` function.
[image]

The interesting part is that I have a "duration" variable, meaning each count took some duration to measure. How can I plot a cumulative plot while taking into account the duration of each measurement? which should produce a much prettier and more accurate graph. (and by that I mean that instead of one large value in the raw data that would cause a large jump in the cumulative graph - we distribute the large value across the time it took to measure this value, resulting in much smoother graph without any jumps)

Here is the code for the data and generating the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_times_test = pd.Series([10.5, 15.2, 15.7, 18.2, 23.0, 25.1, 26.4, 27.4, 31.5, 35.0, 39.4, 48.1])
duration_test = pd.Series([6.2, 2.1, 15.1, 2.7, 1.1, 4.7, 21.2, 6.0, 2.3, 6.2, 1.1, 3.2])
counts_test = pd.Series([7, 5, 130, 3, 2, 12, 262, 19, 5, 32, 3, 7, 10])
cumulative_count_test = (np.cumsum(counts_test))
start_dur_count_df_test = pd.concat([start_times_test, duration_test, counts_test, cumulative_count_test], axis = 1)
start_dur_count_df_test.columns = ["Start_time", 'Duration', "Counts", "Cumulative_counts"]
print(start_dur_count_df_test)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plot1, = ax.plot(start_dur_count_df_test["Start_time"], start_dur_count_df_test["Cumulative_counts"], c="blue", label="regular_plot")
plot2, = ax.plot(start_dur_count_df_test["Start_time"], start_dur_count_df_test["Cumulative_counts"].rolling(window=3).mean(), c="red", label="smoothed_with_rolling")
ax.legend()
plt.savefig('cumulative_plot_test.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where your data came from, but I can assume that `counts_test` depends on the duration of the measurement `duration_test`. This means that plotting `counts_test` without taking the measurement time into account might not be the most accurate way of plotting the data.

A possible solution is to normalize your data `counts_test` by the measurement time `duration_test` to obtain `counts_per_unit_time`. This way, you can plot your data together since they are now independent of the measurement duration:

```
cumulative_count_test = (np.cumsum(counts_test/duration_test))
```

This way the plot turns out smoother and the quantities plotted more homogeneous, which is good, but the most right point of the plot does not represent the total number of counts anymore.

---

EDIT 1

I'm not sure if one can call it elegant, but a possible solution might be converting the timestamps to integer in order to use them as indexes of a numpy array. This allows you to populate the array looping over all the measurements:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_times_test = pd.Series([10.5, 15.2, 15.7, 18.2, 23.0, 25.1, 26.4, 27.4, 31.5, 35.0, 39.4, 48.1])
duration_test = pd.Series([6.2, 2.1, 15.1, 2.7, 1.1, 4.7, 21.2, 6.0, 2.3, 6.2, 1.1, 3.2])
counts_test = pd.Series([7, 5, 130, 3, 2, 12, 262, 19, 5, 32, 3, 7])

### NEW CODE STARTS HERE
## The scale factor is needed to transform the timestamps to integers
## which is needed to use them as array indexes
SCALE_FACTOR = 100
start = start_times_test.values.astype(int)*SCALE_FACTOR
duration = duration_test.values.astype(int)*SCALE_FACTOR
counts = counts_test.values
stops = start + duration

counts_in_bin = np.zeros(max(stops))

for start_index, stop_index, count in zip(start, stops, counts):
    counts_per_unit_of_time = count / (stop_index - start_index)
    counts_in_bin[start_index:stop_index] = counts_in_bin[start_index:stop_index] + counts_per_unit_of_time

cumulative_counts_new = np.cumsum(counts_in_bin)
time_bins = np.linspace(0, max(stops)/SCALE_FACTOR, counts_in_bin.shape[0])
### NEW CODE ENDS HERE

cumulative_count_test = (np.cumsum(counts_test))
start_dur_count_df_test = pd.concat([start_times_test, duration_test, counts_test, cumulative_count_test], axis = 1)
start_dur_count_df_test.columns = ["Start_time", 'Duration', "Counts", "Cumulative_counts"]
print(start_dur_count_df_test)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plot1, = ax.plot(start_dur_count_df_test["Start_time"], start_dur_count_df_test["Cumulative_counts"], c="blue", label="regular_plot")
plot2, = ax.plot(start_dur_count_df_test["Start_time"], start_dur_count_df_test["Cumulative_counts"].rolling(window=3).mean(), c="red", label="smoothed_with_rolling")
plot3, = ax.plot(time_bins, cumulative_counts_new, label='possible solution')
ax.set_xlim(min(start)/SCALE_FACTOR, max(stops)/SCALE_FACTOR)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

ps. I deleted the last element of `counts_test` since its length was 13 instead of 12 like `start_times_test` or `duration_test`

Comment: Well you are correct with your assumptions, and it's not the perfect way to plot. Also, you have a nice idea for normalization though we can't do that since we need the exact count number in the end. I thought it would be best to somehow distribute each count value across the duration but I lack the numpy/pandas knowledge to do that.

Comment: I understand. Is the unit of time of start time test and duration test the same? In other words, are some measurement overlapping?

Comment: Yes, the units are the same, and yes the measurements overlap. My idea to solve this problem was a boring programming way - to iterate through the counts, create lists that show how much was counted each timestep and then plot those (for example we have count with value of 557 and duration of 10  and start time of 13 then it will be a list of ten values [55.7, 55.7...55.7] and those will be calculated in the cumulative graph from time 13 to 23. But it's a very ugly and error prone way and I was hoping there is a more elegant solution with numpy / pandas / matplotlib

Comment: I edited the post with a new solution following more or less what you suggested. I'm not sure how one can avoid the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's a much more elegant solution then what I was thinking.